# MP3/Audio Player

Tags: embed-media

I looked over at devot-ee for something that could play audio files.  I did not see anything that is compatible with EE 2.9+.  Does anyone have suggestions or know of any plugin that could be used?

Answer (score 5):

Any audio player will work with EE. It doesn't need to be an EE specific plugin. Just something you can pass a filename to from an EE field.

Comment: Cool, that is actually what I figured, going to use an html5 with a flash fallback. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: You should accept foamcows answer Vin!